# ASP.NET MVC: Large PDF download fails but large zip downloaded successfully

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, iis

I have a code written to download large (around 160 MB) PDF file. I can download large PDF file in local environment without any issue but same failing in production environment. Also application has functionality to zip the file and then download, now this works perfectly in production. I can download zip (zip file size: 157 MB) of PDF file and zip has approximately same size as that of PDF file.
Error : PDF file download gets started once I click on link and then it gets interrupted in between with message- 'Network Error' in chrome browser. In IE browser message is : "test.pdf download was interrupted". 
I've searched a lot but nothing I could find related to my issue. Can anyone help in finding what could be the issue why it is failing in between with message 'Network Error'?

Below is the code when I download PDF file:

```
//------ this code goes into web tier ------------
public FileResult DownloadFile(int FilePk, string fileName)
{
        try
        {
             //Clear Browser Header Cache
                var browserInformation = Request.Browser;
                Response.ClearHeaders();
                //Set as private if current browser type is IE
                Response.AppendHeader("cache-control", browserInformation.Browser == "IE" ? "private" : "no-cache");

            var pdfFileByte = MyWCFService.GetFile(FilePk); // this service returns byte[]
            return statement.IsNull() ? null : File(pdfFileByte, "Application/pdf", "File-" + "fileName" + ".pdf");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            OnException(ex);
        }

        return null;
    }
//----- this code goes into wcf service which is on app tier---
public byte[] GetFile(int FilePk)
    {
        // Here decalre string filepath variable and get value into it using path present in database
        var fi = new FileInfo(filePath);

        if (!fi.Exists) return null;

        var fileSize = (int)fi.Length;
        var fileInByte = new byte[fileSize];
        using (var fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            fs.Read(fileInByte, 0, fileSize);
        }
        return fileInByte;
    }
```

---

Below is the code when I download zip file:

```
 //------ this code goes into web tier ------------
public FileResult DownloadFileForAll(int exrqPk, string userFileName)
    {
        try
        {

           //Clear Browser Header Cache
                var browserInformation = Request.Browser;
                Response.ClearHeaders();
                //Set as private if current browser type is IE
                Response.AppendHeader("cache-control", browserInformation.Browser == "IE" ? "private" : "no-cache");
            var statement = MyWCFService.GetFileAll(exrqPk);
            return statement.IsNull() ? null : File(statement, "application/zip", userFileName + ".zip");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            OnException(e);
        }
        return null;
    }


----- this code goes into wcf service which is on app tier---
public byte[] GetFileAll(int exrqPk)
    {
        // Here decalre string filepath variable and get value into it using path present in database
        var fi = new FileInfo(filePath);

        if (!fi.Exists) return null;

        var fileSize = (int)fi.Length;
        var fileInByte = new byte[fileSize];
        using (var fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            fs.Read(fileInByte, 0, fileSize);
        }
        return fileInByte;
    }
```

---

Comment: what is the size of your largest zip file?

Comment: @Priyal  it's 180 MB, and I can download it successfully

Comment: and what about your PDF file?

Comment: @Priyal : There are multiple PDF file within range 150 to 200 MB. Example: If single PDF file size is say 160 MB then If I try to zip and download that single file then zip file size would come as 157 MB.